# Unable to use XCode 4 for launching .xcodeproj

Tags: xcode, ios, xcode4, finder

Despite setting XCode (4.0.1) as the default launcher on the info panel of a xcodeproj file and clicking the "Change All" button, xcode projects still seem to launch XCode 3.

My XCode 3.2.5 is installed in /Developer and XCode 4.0.1 in /XCode4

Should this be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.,
Apparently, renaming /Developer to /XCode3 and /XCode4 to /Developer fixed this.

Not sure if anyone else have this issue.

Comment: Yeah, the Applications folder in /Developer is one of the magic applications folders that get searched first, along with /Applications and ~/Applications.  Not sure why "Change All" wouldn't work, but the fix makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to Open XCode4 and load the xcodeproj? If it works, then there's no problem with XCode4 itself. Otherwise, try to use Open With in the context menu.

Comment: Yes that works. Just that registering it as default launcher from Finder doesn't